# How do I configure a synced folder on Vagrant with an absolute path?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm trying to configure the synced folder for Vagrant with a Windows 2012R2 host and Ubuntu 12.04 guest.  I've tried various relative paths with no success.  My installation is on the D: drive and VirtualBox configuration is on the C: drive, so I'm not sure where the default sync location is and am trying to use absolute file paths.  This is the correct Vagrantfile config file because I have been successful making other configurations here such as port forwarding, but I am really struggling to get the synced folder working.

Here is what I am currently trying:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "D:/Users/slittle/vagrant_data", "/home/vagrant/data"
```

The location of my Vagrantfile is D:\Users\slittle and I have folders already created in both of the locations.

Comment: hum, last time I check on windows, this was working - can you try `config.vm.synced_folder "D:\\Users\\slittle\\vagrant_data", "/home/vagrant/data"` ? you confirm `vagrant_data` folder exists under D:/Users/slittle ? what is the output of `vagrant up` for the synced folder part ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.  I check that vagrant_data folder is there too.

Answer (score 2):

As you notice, the double slashes are making the difference:

> config.vm.synced_folder "C:\Users\tash\sync_test", "/home/vagrant"